# How can I use a transistor (2n2222) to act as a switch with this 12V momentary switch?

Tags: arduino, transistors, switches

I have a garage door setup that is basically like the following:

[image: garage door motor activate]

All I want to do is add a new remote switch into the system.

I basically want to add a circuit into the previous schematic in the following place (image cropped for space):

[image: add circuit]

**Bluetooth & Arduino**

What I'm going to do is have a Bluetooth module connected to an Arduino.  When the BT receives a signal (from Android app) then it will make one pin (D10) of the Arduino go high (5V) for a moment then go low again.

I have all that worked out.
What I need now is a circuit that will "connect" the two new wires when the pin goes high.

I'm guessing the circuit will look something like the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXfGv9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**NOTE**:
The schematic is more of a block diagram. I am just trying to show that:

1. The primary circuit (Bluetooth / Arduino) runs at 5V
2. The secondary circuit is the new circuit I'm proposing and will be powered from the same 12V source as the original momentary switch.

Why am I proposing using a 2N2222 (transistor)?  Because I know I have one available.

**My Questions**

1. What would that secondary circuit really look like?
2. Would I just use a resistor between the 12V input and the collector to drop voltage / limit current?
3. Is this possible using the 2N2222 and the proper resistor combination or is it just not feasible due to limitations of the transistor?
4. If it's not possible can you offer the proper components that should be used in that secondary circuit?

Comment: It's very hard to use an NPN transistor as a high side switch (ie, to switch the positive supply to a load) in the way your button does.  It's most likely that your best solution would be to largely start over.  For example, it's really unclear why you need the relay to push the button, when it's going to be on for about the same time that the remote is powered.  If you just wired the button closed, you could probably use the NPN as a low-side switch to directly power the remote or activate the relay to power it...

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ok, well, I have this exact system in place (I use it every day to open/close my garage door from my phone) except it is using a relay component (https://amzn.to/2q8ZTFP) where I'm proposing a transistor.  What I'm wondering is if I can replace the relay component with something smaller and cheaper like a transistor of some type.

Comment: You could use the NPN to control a PNP... but that the homemade circuit you are trying to control is already quite inelegant.   Likely you can get rid of all the relays, wire the garage door button, and just use a regulator having an enable input.  Or control the whole thing with a single relay controlled by either an NPN transistor as a low side switch activated by the arduino, or by your button bypassing that.   You've kind of built yourself into a corner right now, where you either need to make things yet more complicated (such as your 2nd relay), or tear them down and start over.

Comment: :) thanks great stuff.  You guys really know your electronics here. is this better?

Comment: @raddevus Not sure why someone gave you a (-) for the question. At the level you are at I think you put in a yeoman's work into formulating your question as well as possible. I am actually kind of impressed. You provide more of a wiring diagram than a schematic, but who can argue? It takes experience to produce good schematics and, lacking that, a wiring diagram is about all that can be done. I'll add my approval of the question for that effort and the respect it shows in efforts you invested to pose your question well.

Comment: so if you want to basically have a remote control version of the switch, and use the NPN, you'd have to move the switch to the ground side of the circuit and add the parallel control there.  You will want to check the operating current of the system, I don't expect a lot probably under 200mA, but it's always better to check rather than putting all the smoke back in. (TO-92 packages have horrible heat dissipation characteristics.)

Comment: @raddevus You probably need to put a ammeter on your garage door opener system, between the manual switch and the rest of the opener circuitry, and give us an estimated current reading. Probably, you should do this when the system is powered, but otherwise inactive, as well as when it is actively operating the door. Looking for the worst case value you can find (highest) for the current reading. Can you make that measurement?

Comment: @jonk what is being controlled is the garage door's radio transmitter, rather than the receiver/motor unit.  It probably normally runs off a CR2032 coin cell or something only slightly larger, so the current demand will be low.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks. I'm just never sure, I guess. But the circuit may be consistent with that. There are dozens (or hundreds) of high side switch examples on the site. Not sure if much is added by writing another. So the transmitter uses a 12 V relay, right now, to connect two switch input pins of the module? So this must already be a cobbled up design, adding an LED and replacing the earlier push button with a relay driven by said button and adding a regulator? Or is the 3.2 V there because the transmitter power requirements? Something feels kind of wrong when you say "button cell."

Comment: @ChrisStratton I would have guessed more like 12 V automotive circuitry. Which probably means there never was a button cell involved, I'd imagine.

Comment: @jonk the supply is 12v but the LM317 is configured for 3.125 volts and power the transmitter, suggesting it is replacing a coil cell or similar.

Answer (score 5):

A schematic, given what I read above, would be something like the following.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCDncj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've added a resistor in series with the LED because LEDs usually do not directly operate off of \$12\:\text{V}\$ unless they have something built in (resistor, etc) to help with current limiting. It helps me avoid thinking about that problem if it is included. So perhaps I added it more for me, than you. But it's there.

The formula for the output voltage of the LM317 is:

$$V_\text{OUT}=V_\text{REF}\cdot\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)+I_\text{ADJ}\cdot R_2$$

where \$V_\text{REF}=1.25\:\text{V}\pm 50\:\text{mV}\$ and \$I_\text{ADJ}\approx 50\:\mu\text{A}\$. Given your resistor values in your wiring diagram, I compute something close to \$V_\text{OUT}\approx 3.13\:\text{V}\$. Which, I suppose, is possible for the (+) input of your garage door opener.

---

As you can see, \$SW_1\$ is connected to the "high side" of things. (Okay, so I drew it out that way. But it is also following convention to arrange things this way.) So, at first blush, when talking about using transistors then what you want is called a "high side switch." That's important for transistors because they come in two polarities and one is good as a low side switch and the other polarity is good as a high side switch. So it helps to know which kind of switching you are doing so you can quickly select the right polarity of transistor.

You've provided a lot of information. Perhaps almost too much because now we can see "several different ways" to approach a solution. But all of them are probably more complicated than the one you suggested. So I think it is best to stay with that.

The addition isn't that complicated, as you can see below. The main thing is that the "brick" (black box) needs access to ground (or the (-) side of things) as well as the unswitched \$12\:\text{V}\$ supply rail. It also accepts a ground-referenced signal from the Arduino Nano and activates its ***SW+*** output that bypasses the manual switch when the Arduino Nano orders it to do so.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSvWa6.png)</sup>

(Note: The Arduino ground must be in common with your garage door opening system's negative terminal, so make sure that you share the Arduino power supply's ground [or negative side] with the negative side of the garage door system. We don't usually show that connection in a schematic because it is "assumed" that you know it should be there. But if you only wire the I/O pin and do NOT connect up the Arduino ground side also then there will be problems in making this work.)

---

Let's focus on the transistor switch (that black box above.)

The Arduino Nano is operated off of its own \$5\:\text{V}\$ power supply (after regulation, anyway.) This is distinct from the the supplies used in the garage door opener system. The I/O pin will drive out either \$\approx 5\:\text{V}\$ when "HI" or else \$\approx 0\:\text{V}\$ when "LO" (these values are relative to the (-) side of the Arduino Nano power supply.)

The problem right now is that none of us know how much current is required by the relay, the LM317 and the garage door opener module. (We can guess about the LED, though. There are typical values that are reasonably assumed for it.) But I'm convinced that this is a low-current circuit (for now), so I'll treat it as such and use a simple arrangement.

The first idea here is that you need to switch \$12\:\text{V}\$ on the high side. This would suggest a PNP transistor. But to turn a PNP ***off*** you have to make the base voltage very close to the emitter voltage (near a zero volt difference) and this means the base would need to be close to \$12\:\text{V}\$. Sadly, your Arduino Nano cannot achieve that. Not even close. So this means a second BJT is needed and this time, an NPN.

There are two basic approaches at this point. In both, the PNP is operated as a ***switch device***, which means with its collector pulled close to its emitter and that means with a large base current relative to the collector current. However, there are two different ways to go with the NPN -- either as yet another ***switch device*** with similar relative ratios for the base vs collector current, or else as an emitter-follower that works as a current sink, instead. The advantage of this latter case is that the required I/O pin current is quite a bit less and that's a good thing. However, it would not work out if you were switching \$5\:\text{V}\$, for example. It's lucky that in this circumstance you are switching a higher voltage. So that's the path I'm going to take, below.

(Note that while I'm taking this "better path" [according to me], that doesn't mean you will often see it done this way. Most people just fall into the well-worn path of operating both BJTs as switches. It's kind of a rut, of sorts, and folks sometimes seem to have a hard time keeping out of such ruts. But I like to push a little off the beaten path, time to time. So that's why I'm going this way.)

Let's look at the new schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpwInV.png)</sup>

I've assumed a collector current for \$Q_1\$ of about \$200\:\text{mA}\$ and a lowish \$\beta_\text{SAT}\approx 10\$ to make sure it has enough base current (of about \$20\:\text{mA}\$) which determines the collector current for \$Q_2\$. Assuming an I/O pin output of about \$4.8\:\text{V}\$ and a \$V_\text{BE}\$ drop of about \$850\:\text{mV}\$ for \$Q_2\$, I worked out \$R_4=\frac{4.8\:\text{V}-850\:\text{mV}}{20\:\text{mA}}\approx 200\:\Omega\$. A nearby value of \$220\:\Omega\$ was then selected.

The I/O pin current will be about 100 times smaller, so less than \$200\:\mu\text{A}\$, which is easily handled by any I/O pin I've used in decades. So should be just fine.

Dissipation in either BJT will be no more than about \$150\:\text{mW}\$. So small signal BJTs for both will probably survive fine. (Of course, verify things don't get too hot once you build it. I'm making assumptions here.)

I've provided two alternatives, by the way. The one labeled "MINIMAL" is for the minimalist types who just want to use the least number of parts and are willing to take a few risks if they are small ones. In this case, there's a missing DC path resistor that is used to help tie the PNP base upward to its emitter voltage (\$12\:\text{V}\$.) Without that resistor, it's possible though probably not likely, that the PNP will fail to completely turn off. I haven't tested thousands of incarnations to find out what the odds are, but without the resistor it will probably work okay. But it's not as safe to use as the one labeled "BETTER." If you aren't stuck on using the absolute minimum of parts, I'd add \$R_5\$. Cheap, doesn't take up a lot of room, and helps manage a situation that is otherwise left to chance.

Just make sure you "share" the power supply grounds between your Arduino and your garage door opener circuit (tie them together.) (Of course, do not tie the positive rails to each other!) They just need a common reference point and ground (or minus) serves that role.

That's about it, really. I do apologize for using schematics instead of wiring diagrams, which may be easier for you to follow. If you seriously need a wiring diagram (you cannot make such a diagram out of a schematic concept), then I'll try and fabricate one that makes the wiring parts of it clearer.

P.S. Wiring diagrams are more for builders who don't want to understand how it is that what they are building actually works, but instead just want to go build it and pray that it functions right and that diagram is accurate. Schematics are more for those who want to follow and understand what's going on and aren't nearly as interested in the exact wiring details as they are in the functional blocks and how they work together. Two different purposes.

---

Other approaches would be to have your Arduino Nano directly perform the relay function and control conductance between \$SW_\text{A}\$ and \$SW_\text{B}\$ of your module. If you do that directly with transistors somehow, you could eliminate the relay. (Usually, that's a gain and not a loss.) However, this still leaves the power switch, \$SW_1\$, as an issue (do you leave it ***on*** all the time, or what exactly?) And what about the LED?

You could separate the LED out (get rid of it, since it depends on \$12\:\text{V}\$) and replace that part, using another I/O pin of your Arduino Nano to turn on and off an LED operating from its power supply, for example. Then get rid of the relay and work out a circuit to directly connect \$SW_\text{A}\$ and \$SW_\text{B}\$ only after first powering up a different voltage regulator that accepts an ENABLE pin (yet another I/O pin from your Ardiuno Nano.) So, with three I/O pins from your Arduino Nano (one for an LED light, one to enable a voltage regulator, and one to connect \$SW_\text{A}\$ to \$SW_\text{B}\$, you could get rid of the relay entirely and use transistors for everything.

In such a case, you'd make sure the LED is ***off*** and that the connection between \$SW_\text{A}\$ and \$SW_\text{B}\$ is deactivated, then activate the power, wait a decent period of time to let it stabilize, activate the LED to indicate power, then activate the connection between \$SW_\text{A}\$ and \$SW_\text{B}\$ for whatever time you think is needed. Then you'd reverse this process, to return to a quiescent state.

But that's why I said it would be simpler to just go with your own suggested approach. It assumes everything works already, just fine, and adds a simple parallel transistor switch to replace the manual pressing of a button. All you have to do is make sure that you hold the circuit active for the right period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Easily accomplished with a 3904 NPN and a 3906 PNP transistor, shown by the simplified circuit below. The 10K on the base of the 3906 acts as a pull-up resistor to 12v, keeping the base high and the transistor turned off. To turn on the 3906, activate the 3904 (+5v from Arduino) which will ground the 3906's base, turning it (3906) on, allowing the 12v to flow to the positive button input. To turn off, ground the 3904's base, which will shut off the path to ground, and the base of the 3906 will be pulled high again and turn off. Good circuit practice would be to include another resistor between the base of the 3906 and the collector of the 3904 (I will leave this value up to someone more experienced than I), but this will get you going. Excellent reading material: https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/bipolar_transistor_cookbook_part_3

Just in case: The base of both transistors are in the middle, the emitter of the 3906 is on the top, the collector on bottom, and vice versa for the 3904.

**EDIT:** Updated visuals

[image]

[image]

And here is little GIF of the circuit above quickly thrown on a breadboard just for proof of functionality. The LED lighting up is signifying the 12v being switched on through the 3906 PNP transistor, with the LED+ on the 3906 collector, and LED-  to GND.

Comment: I wouldn't try that circuit. When active, bad things would happen. Do you see why? Also, there is a nice schematic editor built into the system for providing answers. It's not difficult to learn to use.

Comment: @jonk  With a 10K pullup, only 1.2mA is flowing from Vcc to GND, a higher value can lower that too. My browser was having issue with circuit lab it at the time.

Comment: No. There is another problem. I guess you cannot see it. Suppose Q1 is "on." This means its collector voltage will be below its base voltage -- very close to ground. This means the base of Q2 is near ground. What do you think that presents, as a voltage, across the base-emitter junction of Q2? What do you think will be the result of this situation? Note: The web page you link doesn't provide an exact match of your example circuit. There are several different ways to fix this that are very close to what you write. But what you have there does require a change (or two.)

Comment: If you fix this correctly, I'll probably not add an answer. But if you don't, I'll probably have to. So I'm really hoping you see the issue and how to remedy it!

Comment: I'm not sure why you didn't just answer it in the first place :).  Anyways I tested the circuit on a breadboard and it works great.

Comment: @jonk I get it it may not be the most perfect circuit, however I've used this circuit a bunch of times in my personal projects, and check the new answer edit: proof of function.

Comment: Fascinating, does Q1 (npn) not get hot with continuous use?

Comment: @HavocRC You are missing at least one resistor. Two resistors if you want to make a fail-safe circuit.

Comment: @HavocRC I think it's great that you went to the trouble. I didn't say it would not do something, even something useful. It's just kind of hard on the BJTs and is a bad example to learn anything from. What happens is that the NPN collector is pulled up hard by the base-emitter PNP diode and there's a bit of a fight of sorts that could result in eventual damage to one or both of the BJTs. Huge base currents will be in the PNP, limited by what beta exists for the NPN, and heating effects. It's just bad design as a system, though some ideas are correct. I'll say no more and instead add an answer.